# Password generator returns blank result

Tags: python

I've tried to create a random password generator with Python but the output returned blank. I'm new to Python and, therefore, can't see where I made a mistake.

```
import random
    letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
    numbers = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
    symbols = ['!', '#', '$', '%', '&', '(', ')', '*', '+']
    
    print("Welcome to the PyPassword Generator!")
    nr_letters= int(input("How many letters would you like in your password?\n")) 
    nr_symbols = int(input(f"How many symbols would you like?\n"))
    nr_numbers = int(input(f"How many numbers would you like?\n"))
    
    characters = [letters, symbols, numbers]
    
    password = ""
#Password within the boundaries
    letter_count = 0
    symbol_count = 0
    number_count = 0
    
    for char in characters[random.randint(0, 2)]:
    
      if letters == char and letter_count <= nr_letters:
          password += letters[random.randint(0, 47)]
          letter_count += 1
    
      elif symbols == char and symbol_count <= nr_symbols:
          password += symbols[random.randint(0, 8)]
          symbol_count += 1
    
      elif numbers == char and number_count <= nr_numbers:
          password += numbers[random.randint(0, 9)]
          number_count += 1
    
      if len(password) == nr_letters + nr_symbols + nr_numbers:
        break
    print(password)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you are not comparing the same "category" of things.

The line `characters[random.randint(0, 2)]:` will return you either one of the list of `letters` / `numbers` / `symbols`.

So for the loop `for char in characters[random.randint(0, 2)]:`, `char` is actually looping through either one of the list, instead of the whole list that you intended. And therefore, `char` will never equal to `letters` / `numbers` / `symbols`.

What you can do to fix it is to change this loop into a while-loop, where the condition is that when the length of the password does not exceed the user input, keep adding a character from a random selection of the list.

```
while len(password) != nr_letters + nr_symbols + nr_numbers:
    selected_list = characters[random.randint(0, 2)]
    
    if letters == selected_list and letter_count < nr_letters:
      password += letters[random.randint(0, 47)]
      letter_count += 1

    elif symbols == selected_list and symbol_count < nr_symbols:
      password += symbols[random.randint(0, 8)]
      symbol_count += 1

    elif numbers == selected_list and number_count < nr_numbers:
      password += numbers[random.randint(0, 9)]
      number_count += 1
    
print(password)
```

Comment: Glad it helps, you may consider choosing this as an accepted answer or upvoting it to make the top for others to see.

Comment: It outputs the right total number of characters, but not the right types of character. For example, if I input 1 letter, 1 number and 1 symbol, it outputs 2 letters and 1 symbol instead of 1 of each.

Comment: That's because you are comparing the count of each category with `<=`, change it to `<` and you will get the correct answer

Comment: I didn't pay attention to that. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

As said before, you are comparing list (letters) to a single character (char). Instead you should ask if character is in the list. Try writing:

```
if char in letters
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess there's something wrong with your logic around the for loop, a while loop seems better in this situation. your comparison for `char` to a list item was causing issues. Hope my solution is understandable and helps.

```
import random


letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v',
           'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R',
           'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
numbers = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
symbols = ['!', '#', '$', '%', '&', '(', ')', '*', '+']

print("Welcome to the PyPassword Generator!")
nr_letters = int(input("How many letters would you like in your password?\n"))
nr_symbols = int(input(f"How many symbols would you like?\n"))
nr_numbers = int(input(f"How many numbers would you like?\n"))

characters = [letters, symbols, numbers]

password = ""
# Password within the boundaries
letter_count = 0
symbol_count = 0
number_count = 0

while len(password) != nr_letters + nr_symbols + nr_numbers:
    number = random.randint(0,2)

    if characters[number] == letters and letter_count <= nr_letters:
        password += letters[random.randint(0, 46)]
        letter_count += 1

    elif characters[number] == symbols and symbol_count <= nr_symbols:
        password += symbols[random.randint(0, 8)]
        symbol_count += 1

    elif characters[number] == numbers and number_count <= nr_numbers:
        password += numbers[random.randint(0, 9)]
        number_count += 1

print(password)
```